# Covariant Power set functor

Tags: category-theory

Just trying to get my head around what it actually means.

Say we have $X=\{1,2,3\}$, and $Y=\{2,4,6\}$. These both belong to the category $\mathbf{Set}$, and the function $f:X\to Y: x\mapsto 2x$ is a morphism in this category.

Then the covariant power set functor $\mathcal{P}:\mathbf{Set}\to \mathbf{Set}$ sends $X$ to $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and $Y$ to $\{\emptyset,\{2\},\{4\},\{6\},\{2,4\},\{4,6\},\{4,6\},\{2,4,6\}\}$.

But what does it send $f$ to? Does it send it to $\{f_1:\{1\}\to\{2\},f_2:\{2\}\to\{4\},...,f_8:\{1,2,3\}\to\{2,4,6\}\}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(f) \colon x \mapsto f[x] \colon \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y) sends $x \subseteq X$ to its image under $f$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close.

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function then $\mathcal Pf:\mathcal PX\to\mathcal PY$ is a function prescribed by $$A\mapsto\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$$

In words: sets are sent to their image under  $f$.

Comment: Oh ok, so in the above example, $\{1,2\}\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ gets sent to $\{f(1),f(2)\}\in\mathcal{P}(Y)\}$. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Glad to help.