# Can we apply a function to a set? What does $f(A)$ mean when $A$ is a set of numbers?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For eg., let  $ A = \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2 ,3\} $

Let $f(x) = \lfloor \frac {x^2}{3}\rfloor $

What is $ f(A) $ ?

In case anyone is wondering, this is homework, but I am not sure how to proceed as I can't find anything online regarding this.

Answer (score 13):

$f$ has been defined as a function on numbers (of some kind). Its domain and codomain comprise numbers (not sets of numbers).

So $f$ acts on numbers, not sets. We can't, so to speak "pass a set through" this function. Without further explanation, $f(A)$ makes no sense, and the question "what is $f(A)$?" is simply ill-defined.

But as Patrick Stevens points out, there is a common bad(?) habit of using something like '$f(A)$' to mean $\{f(x) \colon x \in A\}$. Note however that with the notation understood this way, when we evaluate $f(A)$ we are still not "passing the *set* [of numbers] through the function", we are passing *numbers* (members of the set $A$) to the function!

That use of '$f(A)$' can however lead to tangles in some situations, and since we have alternative unambiguous notations for the same thing (the simple one I like is '$f[A]$'), it is best avoided. But if the slang(?!) usage is intended, as is probably the case, then Patrick gives the answer!

Comment: $f_*$ is common in some contexts, the subscript meaning "the (forward) map induced by $f$ on whatever construction we've built on its domain and codomain", in this case the power sets. (and $f^*$ to denote the inverse image map, with basically the same interpretation except it's the "backward" map)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, we can, but it's an abuse of notation. To be really strict (though only a set theorist or logician is likely to be this strict, hence why Peter answered in the negative!), [you'd write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Notation_for_image_and_inverse_image) $f"A$ or $f^{\to}(A)$, but it's clear from context what $f(A)$ is supposed to mean: the image of everything in $A$ under $f$.

In your case, you want $$f"A = \left\{\left\lfloor \frac{x^2}{3} \right\rfloor: x \in A\right\}$$
which is $\{0,1,3\}$.

Comment: With the initial abuse of notation, I am somewhat concerned that the expected answer by the instructor might be the likewise-abusive $\{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3\}$.

Comment: `f(A)` is a fairly common abuse of notation for `f"A`.  The instructor expecting an ordered multiset would be a more egregious abuse that I wouldn't expect.

Comment: Alternately, $\mathcal P(f)(A)$ or $\mathcal P f(A)$, where here $\mathcal P$ is the power set endofunctor on $\mathbf{Set}$ acting on the arrow $f$.

Comment: @wchargin: Did I just have a stroke?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I hope not—what was unclear? :-) I was offering an alternate, perhaps more familiar way to notate $f " A$ or $f^\rightarrow(A)$ (neither of which I have personally seen before). For instance, this post contains an explicit definition: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1487921/15886