# Let E be the set of all even numbers, lets define a function f: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

where $f(X)=X \cap E$. find $f(B), f^{-1}(C)$ where $B=${{$3k:k \in \mathbb{Z}$}$,\emptyset$}, $C=${$ \mathbb{N},\emptyset$}
I'm pretty sure $f(B)$={{$6k:k\in \mathbb{Z}$}}, but can't seem to work out how $C$ can even exist considering that if $X\cap E=C$ then E must contain an empty set,which it doesn't, and all natural odd numbers, which it doesn't.

Comment: You need to look at the elements of $C$ and then collect them together. That is, $f^{-1}(C) = \{f^{-1}(\emptyset) ,f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})\}$. You may refer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193273/can-we-apply-a-function-to-a-set-what-does-fa-mean-when-a-is-a-set-of-num

Comment: @mertunsal is $f^{-1}(C)=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}\backslash E)$?

Comment: edit: $f^{-1}(C)=${$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}\backslash E),\emptyset$}